# Configuring Reportportal with Java +TestNG or Java + Log4j

Tags: log4j, testng, reporting, test-reporting, reportportal

Have been trying to configure Reportportal withe a sample project. The following steps have been done:

  1.Start a Docker and get the reportporal page up and running.

  2.In the Java project, added the bintray repository, java-agent-testng, logger-java-log4j dependencies.

  3.Included log4j.properties file in the project and also the log4j.appender line for reprortportal

```
log4j.appender.reportportal=com.epam.ta.reportportal.log4j.appender.ReportPortalAppender
log4j.appender.reportportal.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.reportportal.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

  4.Included log4j info lines for one of the @Test methods.

  5.Ran the Test script and made sure the log info line is seen on the console.

  6.However, the reportportal dashboard still shows "No Results Found"

  7.Also, added the following line for the Test Method.

```
@Listeners({ReportPortalTestNGListener.class})
```

  8. This threw an exception with Jackson.

A few questions running in my mind:

  1.Do we need both TestNG and Log4j to integrate with reportportal or just one of them is fine.

  2. With the above steps carried out, is there anything that has been missed. Why am I not seeing data on my reportportal dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

I only did this using the testNG integration. We do have log4j but didn't needed that to post the tests in RP. 
I do not however, have any screenshots or attachments.I think that is log4j integration.

Comment: could you please throw more insight on your testNG integration with ReportPortal, as to what all needs to be configured and the workflow basically. This would be of great help

Comment: From the documentation: 
https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-testNG

In my case it is gradle so I added in the build.gradle file the below
The repo:     maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal" }
The dependencies for the loggers:     
    compile "com.epam.reportportal:agent-java-testng:4.2.1"
    compile "com.epam.reportportal:logger-java-logback:3.0.0"
    compile "com.epam.reportportal:logger-java-log4j:3.0.0"

The listener:
            listeners << 'com.epam.reportportal.testng.ReportPortalTestNGListener'

Comment: Then in the `src/main/resources` just add the `reportportal.properies` file which has  the connection details to your portal.
rp.endpoint = http://localhost:8080
rp.uuid = 'get that from your profile dropdown tab'
rp.launch = 'just a launch name
rp.project = 'your project name'

Again this does not send attached files/screenshots as that requires implementation in the logger side.

Comment: Thanks @Stefanos Varsanis, tried again with your suggestion, but no luck. Please help me out on this https://github.com/chethanr18/ReportPortalTest.git . That's the link for a  Test project on which I'm trying this out. Let me know if something has been missed. Also please note that, I'm using "Play with Docker" plugin, for the Docker setup.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

@Chethan Swaroop
TestNG integration will send events as `testStarted`, `testEnded` into ReportPortal.

This will help to represent structure of test cases and statuses in RP.

Log4J integration (logger appender) will forward logs output into RP server, associating log line with active test case at the moment.

You can have only testNG integration, without logs (log4j), but you can't have log4j, without testing engine integration (testNG in you case)

Please try examples with you local ReportPortal instance:

https://github.com/reportportal/example-java-TestNG/tree/master/logback/src/main/java/com/epam/rp/tests